# x64 Assembler jmp using a table of offsets

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

For efficiency I want to use a table of addresses that I can index by a register to jmp to within an assembler routine.

An example might make this clearer...

```
.CODE   
...
AppendByte  PROC
    XOR     RAX, RAX
    MOV     AL,  CL     ; Get this 0-7 index from somewhere else
    JMP     QWORD PTR[RAX + OFFSET APPENDBYTETABLE]
AppendByte  ENDP

AppendByte_7:
    ; Do stuff...
    RET

AppendByte_6:
    ; Do stuff...
    RET

...
AppendByte_0:
    RET

.DATA
    APPENDBYTETABLE QWORD   AppendByte_0, AppendByte_1, AppendByte_2,
                            AppendByte_3, AppendByte_4, AppendByte_5,
                            AppendByte_6, AppendByte_7

END
```

This compiles in VS2017 but I then get a linker error.
I think this relates to using FAR addresses.  How do I generate NEAR offsets and perform a SHORT jmp to offsets stored in a table in the DATA segment?

Note that if I put the AppendByte_x labels inside my proc then the compiler croaks.

RESOLVED! EDIT after advise from Fuz...

```
XOR         RAX, RAX
MOV         AL, REG_PREFIXCODEBITS  
LEA         RCX, APPENDBYTETABLE
JMP         QWORD PTR [RCX + RAX * 8]
```

Comment: What linker error do you get exactly? “I get an error” is not a useful error description.

Comment: Appologies, and thanks for the quick response!
The error:
1>first.obj : error LNK2017: 'ADDR32' relocation to 'APPENDBYTETABLE' invalid without /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1165: link failed because of fixup errors

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is; let me write an answer.

Comment: Try replacing `jmp qword ptr [rax + offset APPENDBYTETABLE]` with `lea rcx, APPENDBYTETABLE` and then `jmp qword ptr [rcx + rax]`.  Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go at lunch time :)

Comment: Also note that you might need `rax*8` instead of just `rax` if the index is really in the range 0–7.

Comment: Is this the way YOU would do this?  I.e.  Is there a way to perform a NEAR jump and not use QWORDs in the table?
I'm fairly new to ML64.

Comment: @neaproc This is not about near and far jumps; far jumps are related to segmentation which isn't really a thing in amd64 assembly.  While I'm not too familiar with Microsoft's toolchain, I believe the problem is that memory operands only take 32 bit displacements but the linker wants to allow your program to be loaded to memory above address 2³².  This can be avoided using `lea` to grab the address of `APPENDBYTETABLE` using an `rip` relative addressing mode.  If this is the solution to the problem, I can write a detailed answer for you, but I want to be sure that it works first.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: BRILLIANT!  Compiles and links successfully now.
You certainly know your stuff!

Comment: Could I also use OFFSET instead of LEA?

Comment: I'm not sure, but anyway `lea` has the shorter encoding so it should be preferred.  Let me write up an answer for you.

Comment: By that comment I mean...
MOV         AL, REG_PREFIXCODEBITS  
MOV         RCX, OFFSET APPENDBYTETABLE
JMP         QWORD PTR [RCX + RAX * 8]

Comment: Ok thanks I'll stick with LEA.

Comment: Curious as to where you picked up your expansive assembler skills, know any good resources?

Comment: I picked up most of that by observing what kind of assembly the compiler generates and from countless resources on the internet.  I haven't really followed a tutorial on that subject.

Comment: Well, either way I'm impressed.  Thanks again :)

Comment: unrelated: you want `movzx eax, cl` for efficiency, not xor-zero + a byte merge.  It's smaller and faster (zero latency on IvyBridge and later).  [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342)  You probably also want `jmp [table + rax*8]`, because the entries are 8 bytes each.  Or if a disp32 won't link, then you should use a RIP-relative LEA like suggested.  But anyway, you definitely want to take advantage of `movzx`.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I am not very familiar with Microsoft's toolchain, I believe the main problem is  that in SIB (scale/index/base) addressing modes such as `[RAX + OFFSET APPENDBYTETABLE]`, the displacement is limited to either one or four bytes. The Microsoft linker wants to make your program loadable from any address, including those above the first 4 GB address space, requiring the full 8 bytes to represent an address.  Obviously, 4 bytes are not enough to fit 8 bytes, so the linker rightfully complains.

To fix this, you have to first load a register with the address of `APPENDBYTETABLE` and then index into the table.  The general way to do this is to use a `lea`  (load effective address) instruction.  `lea rax, foo`  is like `mov rax, foo` but instead of loading the memory at `foo`, the address of `foo` is returned.  This can be used in conjunction with a `rip` (instruction pointer) relative addressing mode to fetch the address of `APPENDBYTETABLE` despite the displacement being again limited to 4 bytes.  This is because the linker assumes that each program or DLL is individually smaller than 2 GB, so a signed 32 bit offset is always enough to find the address of a variable or function relative to the location of the current instruction.  The assembler implicitly chooses a `rip` relative addressing mode when you access a variable directly without using an index register or SIB addressing mode:

```
lea rax, APPENDBYTETABLE   ; load address of APPENDBYTETABLE rip-relative
```

You can of course also use `mov reg, offset foo` to load the address of `foo`.  This uses a form of `mov` with an 8 byte immediate.  However, this instruction has a longer encoding than `lea reg, foo`, is likely slower, and potentially requires the loader to patch in the correct address at runtime, slowing down the start of your program.  Just stick with `lea` if there is no good reason to do otherwise.